# Regex works on test sites but not in Java

Tags: java

I created a regex and tested it on regex tes sites where it works.. But When I try to use it in my Code it can't find any matches.

Possible input:

```
"1 Question 1"
"1X some random text"
```

My regex looks like this: ([0-9]+X? )(.*)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+X? )(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
String id = matcher.group(1);
String question = matcher.group(2);
```

Result I get from Regex Test sites:

[text 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTpus.png)

[text 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWk7e.png)

Comment: you need to call `matcher.matches()` or `matcher.find()` before you use `group()`

Comment: Thank you.. My fault for not reading the documentation well enough

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to check if pattern match the input string or not. Check this out:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
//        String line = "1 Question 1";
    String line = "1X some random text";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+X? )(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String id = matcher.group(1);
        String question = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.println("id: " + id);
        System.out.println("question: " + question);
    } else
        System.err.println("not match");
}
```